# TypeError: layer should be provided

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am updating an old demo that used the first versions of Cartodb so that is runs with the latest version of cartodb.js.

I am trying to overlay a set of points on the base map and getting the following error:

TypeError: layer should be provided
cartodb.createLayer(b=Object { map_canvas="map_canvas", map="map", user_name="tobagoborn", more...}, d=undefined, e=undefined, f=undefined)cartodb.js (line 23)
initialize()lndngsites1.html (line 56)
onload(event=load )

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize()
{
    var map = new L.Map('map_canvas',
    {
        doubleClickZoom:true,zoomControl:true,scrollWheelZoom: false,touchZoom: false,dragging: true, minZoom: 11, maxZoom: 13
    }).setView(new L.LatLng(11.23,  -60.70), 6);

    var tilesUrl = 'http://tobagoborn.com/tiles/tobagobasemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    L.tileLayer(tilesUrl, {attribution: "Cartodb", maxZoom: 13}).addTo(map);

    //alert(cartodb.VERSION)

    cartodb_leaflet1 = cartodb.createLayer(
    {
        map_canvas: 'map_canvas',
        map: 'map',
        user_name:"tobagoborn",
        type: cartodb,
        sublayers: [{
            table_name: 'lsites',
            query: "SELECT * FROM {{table_name}}",
            interactivity: "landing_sites,number_of_boats,top_species,site_code"
        }]
  }).addTo(map_canvas)

}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using old CartoDB.js versions, perhaps you also find interesting this upgrade guide: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/UPGRADE.md

Comment: @iriberri Thanks for the link.  Read it but got stuck on the type: option.  See my comment to Jags answer

Comment: It turns out that my links to cartodb's css and js scripts were not correct!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how old your previous version was but the syntax looks a little off from what the docs specify. Take a look here;

http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/layer-source-object/#named-maps-layer-source-object-type-namedmap

They have recently updated this section of the documentation after I very recently had queries/complaints. It is still missing some vital information but it is better than it was (for example they don't mention including an empty layer if you are not using their base map, and we found it necessary to avoid issues with infowindows).

You want something likes this;

```
cartodb_leaflet1 = cartodb.createLayer(map, 
{
    user_name:"tobagoborn",
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [
      {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM lsites",
        cartocss: '#lsites {marker-fill: #FF0000;}',
        interactivity['landing_sites','number_of_boats','top_species', 'site_code']
      }]
  })
  .addTo(map)
  .on('done', function(layer) {
      for (var i=0; i < layer.getSubLayerCount(); i++) {
          layer.getSubLayer(i).show();
          layer.getSubLayer(i).setInteraction(true);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried it an getting an error on type:cartodb.  

The error is: TypeError: a.toLowerCase is not a function
Is the any documentation on the type option.

Comment: With which old CartoDB.js version where you working exactly? In this response, I'm missing the cartocss parameter for the sublayers. Find an example of mine of a basic createLayer (which doesn't contain interactivity, tho) here: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/46ea069744d7f852f2bd

Comment: I created the app with version 1. Figured out the TypeError issue... I forgot the quotes!! The problem I'm having now is the layer being loaded but not showing

Comment: I'm not sure why the layer would not be showing. You could potentially provide a snapshot of your data and a log of the loaded layer that we could have a look at? I have edited my answer to show the `on('done')` section of code. Depending on how you have configured the layer in the backend sometimes you need to explicitly show the layer. Also you will also need to set interaction to true to interact with your layer.

Comment: @Jags, I added the done option and for loop but haven't seen any response to it. Also, in the console I see the following error: "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://1.api.cartocdn.com/tobagoborn/api/v1/map/undefined/11/677/960.png".  How do I upload a the log and some of the data  to SO?

Comment: @ChrisJ I edited my answer again. I had copied your sublayer options from your question and accidentally had 'query' instead of 'sql'. Try changing the 'query' property.

Comment: @ChrisJ also a 400 response suggests that the request you sent to the API is malformed, and not conforming to the expected syntax.

Comment: @ChrisJ I see someone has answered another question you have that is similar. I have again edited my answer and tested your code. A couple of points to note. I have removed the empty layer from my answer, it was necessary for my map but does not work with yours. I have also added in the cartocss, as the layer will not display without it. I have had some issues with interactivity on your map, but have not had the time to look at that for now.